# Generate VCard and Send Via Twilio

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, sms, twilio

I am writing a Twilio + Parse app which lets users share their contact info via SMS. I have a sample Vcard as a string in javascript:

```
  message = '';
  message += 'BEGIN:VCARD';
  message += 'BDAY;VALUE=DATE:1963-09-21';
  message += 'VERSION:3.0';
  message += 'N:Stenerson;Derik';
  message += 'FN:Derik Stenerson';
  message += 'ORG:Microsoft Corporation';
  message += 'ADR;TYPE=WORK,POSTAL,PARCEL:;;One Microsoft Way;Redmond;WA;98052-6399;USA';
  message += 'TEL;TYPE=WORK,MSG:+1-425-936-5522';
  message += 'TEL;TYPE=WORK,FAX:+1-425-936-7329';
  message += 'EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:deriks@Microsoft.com';
  message += 'END:VCARD';
  message += 'BEGIN:VCARD';
  message += 'VERSION:3.0';
  message += 'N:Ganguly;Anik';
  message += 'FN:Anik Ganguly';
  message += 'ORG: Open Text Inc.';
  message += 'ADR;TYPE=WORK,POSTAL,PARCEL:;Suite 101;38777 West Six Mile Road;Livonia;MI;48152;USA';
  message += 'TEL;TYPE=WORK,MSG:+1-734-542-5955';
  message += 'EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:ganguly@acm.org';
  message += 'END:VCARD';
  message += 'BEGIN:VCARD';
  message += 'VERSION:3.0';
  message += 'N:Moskowitz;Robert';
  message += 'FN:Robert Moskowitz';
  message += 'EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:rgm-ietf@htt-consult.com';
  message += 'END:VCARD';
```

And I am trying to figure out how to send this to a phone number as a vcard so the phone detects it instead of the text.

I have a method:

```
function respondWithMessage(message, response) {
  response.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  var xmlVersion = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n';
  message = '<Message>\n' + message + '\n</Message>';
  message = '<Response>\n' + message + '\n</Response>';
  message = xmlVersion + message;
  response.send(message);
}
```

With which I am able to send text messages.
In their documentation, Twilio states that text/vcard messages are supported here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/accepted-mime-types
But I have been unable to get it to work.
Could you provide an example of how to send this VCard via SMS with Twilio?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to respond with a vCard, or are just send it? Because you won't be able to wrap a vCard in TwiML, which is what you're tying to do. Can you please give more information?

Comment: I'm trying to generate a vCard from the user's contact information which is stored on my server and send this via SMS to another user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here. If you're trying to start a new message, then you don't need to use TwiML, but can simply use the rest API to send the information from your server.

With Parse.com it should be something like the following:

```
// Require and initialize the Twilio module with your credentials
var client = require('twilio')('ACCOUNT_SID', 'AUTH_TOKEN');

// Send an SMS message
client.sendSms({
    to:'to', 
    from: 'from', 
    body: 'Hello world!',
    mediaUrl: your-vcard-url
  }, function(err, responseData) { 
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else { 
      console.log(responseData.from); 
      console.log(responseData.body);
    }
  }
);
```

So all you need to do now, is make sure `your-vcard-url` is accessible by Twilio, and that its mime type is set to be `text/vcard`.

In other words, you can't just send the contents of the vcard via text message, but need to tell Twilio where the vcard actually is, so it includes it in the message.

An example of a valid URL for a vcard would be [this one](http://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/vcard-examples/john-doe.vcf). Hope this helps you

Comment: I'm trying this using the method described above but I've noticed that Twilio is sending the VCard linked in a Twilio URL, rather than a native looking VCard in the message. I'm testing on iOS.

Comment: I'm actually sending back Twilio their contact url "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC1fc1c1722444b0c6313d3da988bb110f/Messages/MMeeb83b60f78d2ff4c1a19095da372654/Media/ME9d2dce1f2df96248aa691e240bddc12a" via the MediaUrl argument and I still get back as one big large text message. What gives?

Answer (score 8):

## How to send

To send a contact card in Twilio is pretty simple, use this curl command and it should work:

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/<account sid>/Messages.json \
--data-urlencode "Body=Your Heart Health Coach contact card" \
--data-urlencode "MediaUrl=https://mighty-health-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/vcf/James%20Li.vcf" \
--data-urlencode "From=<from>" \
--data-urlencode "To=<to>" \
-u <account sid>:<auth token>
```

You can actually use that vCard linked in the request for testing purposes.

## What can go wrong

If your header are not properly configured, the contact card will not render properly on your iOS/Android phone, even though it seems to be a correct contact card.

#### Headers

The contact card on iOS can only display the same text as of your file, so name your file with the same `filename` header property on `Content-Type` and it should work accordingly

```
Content-Type: text/x-vcard
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="<You file name>.vcf"
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

#### Cached file

1. When Twilio receives a file for the first time, it caches
2. If you adjust the headers accordingly it won't impact the delivery of the VCF file, because it will use the cached version
3. There is a way to overcome that

Make sure you submit it correctly from the first time, or you'll have to the the changes I suggest below

#### Twilio Caching

To remove the caching on your files or to set the appropriate cache policy, read: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024716314-How-Can-I-Change-the-Cache-Behavior-or-Message-Media-Files-

Troubleshooting I figured out that Twilio don't change cache based only on filename for VCF files, but by the file content itself, so you have to modify your file in order for it to clear the cache, not just the name.

Comment: THANKS! That saved me a ton of testing time. Slight modification to @felipeclopes answer.  There the Content-Type and the Content-Disposition were swapped. I used:

`response['Content-Type'] = 'text/vcard';`
`response['Content-Disposition'] = f'inline; filename="Full Name Here.vcf"';`
`response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'`

Comment: Although `Content-Disposition: inline; filename="file.vcf"` 
works for me, this doc implies that it should be `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.vcf"` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: Dumb question here but where do I set the header when sending out a message?

Comment: @FabricioG it is the response header to the request for the file linked in the MediaUrl

Comment: I want to respond with a vcard to all new customers. Can I use a vcard from outlook? Is there a easy way to set this up? the only curl i know is chees curls