# Send vCard using Twilio MMS

Tags: c#, sms, twilio, mms, vcf-vcard

I am building application using twilio MMS which can send the contact detail to user and User can directly store the contact on the phone.

They are showing here(https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/accepted-mime-types) that 'text/vcard' is accepted MIME type but as I send the MMS using twilio to my phone, it converts the vcard to link and that link opens in mobile browser.

So, Provide me the solution or suggest me the other way if possible for sending the vcard using twilio.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Twilio is only currently able to send MMS messages to numbers in the US and Canada](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-i-send-or-receive-mms-messages). If you try to send an MMS message to a number that is not in the US or Canada then the attachment is replaced with a link, as you are experiencing. I'm afraid that if you are sending to other countries then this is the only option at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `text/x-vcard` that is what ended up working for me

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675283/generate-vcard-and-send-via-twilio/58175668#58175668