# Vcard is not being properly received on an Android device Using Twilio api

Tags: c#, android, twilio

**Backgroud:**

I am currently building a C# app for my company that will send vcards to users.  I have researched this a bit and found an article which made sense to me: [Generate VCard and Send Via Twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675283/generate-vcard-and-send-via-twilio?rq=1). I am currently using the vcard which the example gives (see [Sample vcard](http://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/vcard-examples/john-doe.vcf) )
to create a test code block.

**Problem:**

I have tested the functionality with my iPhone device and the app receives the vcard without any issues.  However, with my Android device I do not get the vcard at all.  I went ahead and made two examples of using the Twilio sdk and making an http call.  However, they both seem to have issues with my Android device.  Is this a known issue? I am new to Twilio technology and would appreciate some help.

**Code Snippet 1**

```
TwilioClient.Init(account, token);

var mediaUrl = new List<Uri>() {
        new Uri("http://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/vcard-examples/john-doe.vcf")
    };
var to = new PhoneNumber("+myNumber");
var message = MessageResource.Create(
              to,
              from: new PhoneNumber("+twilionumber"),
              body: "Test1",
              mediaUrl: mediaUrl);
```

**Code Snippet 2**

```
string targeturi = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/" + account + "/Messages.json";
HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = CreateBasicAuthenticationHeader(account,token);
StringContent content = new StringContent(string.Format("From=+twilionumber&To=mynumber&Body=http://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/vcard-examples/john-doe.vcf&MmsOnly=True"));
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpResponseMessage hrm = await hc.PostAsync(string.Format(targeturi, account), content);
if (hrm.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  var stop =0;
}
```

Comment: Did you check for any error/warning on your Twilio account logs?