# Twilio - Sending vCard Not Rendering Properly

Tags: php, twilio, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to send a contact card (.vcf) via Twilio (php) and can't seem to get the vcf to render properly.

The .vcf saves to my server fine, and if I subsequently download the file from the server and open in an iMessage on my iPhone or Mac, it displays just fine. But when sending via Twilio, all I see is the .vcf contents in plain text.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$account_sid = 'xxxxxxxx';
$auth_token  = 'xxxxxxxx';

$client      = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);

header('content-type: text/vcard');  
header('content-disposition: inline; filename= "testing2.vcf"'); 
                
try {

    $vCard = "BEGIN:VCARD\r";
    $vCard .= "VERSION:4.0\r";
    $vCard .= "N:Gump;Forrest;;Mr.;\r";
    $vCard .= "FN:Forrest Gump\r";
    $vCard .= "ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.\r";
    $vCard .= "TITLE:Shrimp Man\r";
    $vCard .= "PHOTO;MEDIATYPE=image/gif:http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif\r";
    $vCard .= "TEL;TYPE=work,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-111-555-1212\r";
    $vCard .= "TEL;TYPE=home,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-404-555-1212\r";
    $vCard .= "EMAIL:forrestgump@example.com\r";
    $vCard .= "END:VCARD";
 
    $path = '/var/www/xxxx/xxxx/testing2.vcf';
    file_put_contents($path, $vCard);

    $client->account->messages->create(array(
        'To' => $user_mobile,
        'MediaUrl' => ['https://www.example.com/vcfs/testing2.vcf'],
        'From' => "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ));
    
}

catch (\Services_Twilio_RestException $e) {
    
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the curl response I get from the URL used in MediaURL, indicating it is indeed a vcard format.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 24 Feb 2021 04:13:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 Feb 2021 05:28:59 GMT
ETag: "15f-5bbfa320d710f"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 351
Content-Type: text/vcard
```

Comment: Is the Url noted in `MediaUrl` (`xxxxxxxxxx/testing2.vcf`) an actual Url which returns data with content type set to `text/vcard`? Usually you would have separate endpoints, one to send out the message via `$client->account->messages->create` and then another to create the contact card on the fly and return it.

Comment: @yvesonline - in the current setup, 1. vcf created. 2. vcf uploaded. 3. message sent with direct path to the vcf on our server. You're suggesting I need set the MediaUrl to an API endpoint which serves the vcf indirectly?

Comment: Yes, as the attribute suggests it's an URL you're pointing to not a server path. You can test it beforehand by putting a (manually created) vcf on a S3 storage bucket (or similar, somewhere where it's statically served) and see if this solves your problem.

Comment: @yvesonline - sorry, I should have been more clear. We ARE using a URL in MediaURL (https://www.example.com/vcfs/testing2.vcf). Like I mentioned in the question, when we visit this URL on iPhone or Mac, it opens up the vCard just fine. For some reason, Twilio messages display it as plaintext

Comment: Ah OK, then when you do a `curl` to your URL under `example.com/vcfs/testing2.vcf`, does it come back with the correct `Content-Type` of `text/vcard`?

Comment: @yvesonline - just posted an update to the question with the curl response - but yeah, it's coming back as test/vcard

Comment: This SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675283/generate-vcard-and-send-via-twilio/58175668#58175668 has some more caveats to pay attention to: are the following headers set? `Cache-Control: no-cache` & `Content-Disposition: inline; filename="testing2.vcf"`? Did you maybe run into the caching issue? They also use `Content-Type: text/x-vcard` as content type.

Comment: @yvesonline - thanks so much for pointing me in that direction (not sure how I didn't find that SO question in the first place). Setting Content-Disposition: inline; filename=FILENAME for .vcf files on my apache server did the trick!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! I added it as an answer for reference and to collect some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the endpoint which serves your vCard sets the following headers:

- `Content-Type: text/vcard`,
- `Cache-Control: no-cache` and
- `Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.vcf"`

See also this SO question: [Generate VCard and Send Via Twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675283/generate-vcard-and-send-via-twilio/58175668#58175668)

Comment: The Content-Type should actually be text/x-vcard, but this works